# UFW rules for dynamic IP VPN

Tags: vpn, ufw

I use VPN in Ubuntu with UFW rules prohibiting traffic leaks in case if VPN connection lost.

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out on XYZ to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX # where XXX - network interface card, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - VPN server IP address
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 # allow outgoing for VPN interface
```

Unfortunately my VPN provider has stopped providing a list of IP addresses of VPN servers and I can no longer create UFW rules. Other VPN providers that suit me also do not provide IP address lists.
According to support, they do not provide lists of IP addresses for user security, but to prevent traffic leakage, they suggest me installing a proprietary VPN client. For a number of reasons, I don’t want to install third-party VPN clients.

Please help me configure UFW, provided that every time I turn on the VPN, I get a random IP address. 
If that matters, I use the * .ovpn configuration file imported into Network Manager to configure and connect to the VPN.

Comment: it is correct to get different IP address when connecting to a VPN, basically it connects you to the best available and stable IP. As for the UFW if you're using a VPN service most of them have firewall implemented and connection encrypted, so it's not much required to use extra Firewall, in some cases it can even interrupt the internet connection.